# Calculate Acitivity Factor in VLSI

Tags: cmos, vlsi

Here is the problem:

[image]

And this is my solution: activity factor = probility output node is 1 x (1 - probility output node is 1)
[image]

Source: E., W.N.H. and Harris, D.M. (2011) CMOS VLSI Design: A circuits and systems perspective. Boston, MA: Pearson Education.  Page: 209.

Comment: Are you in fact asking if your definition of activity factor is correct?

Comment: I think the definition is correct. So, is my activity factor correct?

Comment: Personally speaking, from memory (an old, old one) I don't think that is the definition I recall learning. I recall it had something to do with rising edges.